# Is Ctrl+c disabled to copy a file in lib jar in IDEA 15?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image]

I just update IDEA to 15 from 11, now I find I can't copy a file in libraty jar to my project. Is it disabled in IDEA 15? As in the screenshot,the hot key is gray.I tried copy in IDEA11, it's ok.

Comment: Do you need to copy it in your project? Can't you set up a dependency via for example `maven` ?

Comment: This package is just included for reading, and I just want to copy and overwrite it.